# SQL Query of matching rows in 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. How can I create a query that searches both tables and only returns rows that have the exact same information in all three columns?

For example these are the two tables. Can I make a query that would return the Steve Heinrich row because they are the same in both tables?

```
ID   Firstname   Lastname

01   Bob         Freeman 
02   Steve       Heinrich
03   Jill        Brown
04   Larry       Jordan


ID   Firstname   Lastname

01   Bill        Parson
03   Jack        Daniels
02   Steve       Heinrich
04   Joe         Morgan
```

Comment: what you wrote so far? please show us your query?

Comment: are you using any Joins anywhere that's a start..

Answer (score 2):

If they are the same in both tables, then they are in the first table.  So, you can use `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where exists (select 1
              from t2
              where t1.id = t2.id and t1.firstname = t2.firstname and
                    t1.lastname = t2.lastname
             );
```

This is standard SQL so it should work in all databases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) on ID and Firstname and Lastname

Comment: Great example link, Deserve +1

Answer (score 0):

Do an inner join of both tables with joining conditions on all three columns:

```
select tableA.*
from 
tableA
inner join tableB

where
tableA.Id = tableB.Id
and tableA.FirstName = tableB.FirstName
and tableA.LastName = tableB.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT** *

**FROM** table1

**INNER JOIN** table2

**ON** table1.ID = table2.ID AND

table1.Firstname = table2.Firstname AND

table1.Lastname = table2.Lastname;